# Flutter testing - forms

Tags: flutter-test

I have tried testing in flutter with **flutter_test** and **flutter_driver**. Able to achieve UI testing with tap functions. But my requirement is to test forms end to end(i.e automatically fill forms). Facing issue with **driver.enterText()**, its not getting executed and the test cases stops executing from here.

Below is the code that i have tried :

```
test('Going back to customers tab', () async {
      // First, tap the button.
      final customerTabFinder = find.text('Customers');
      await driver.waitFor(customerTabFinder);
      await driver.tap(customerTabFinder);
      await driver.getText(find.text("Customer"));
      await takeScreenshot(driver, 'screenshots/incremented1.png');
    });

    test("Adding customers", () async {
      final pressAddCustomerButton = find.byTooltip("Increment");

      await driver.waitFor(pressAddCustomerButton);
      await driver.tap(pressAddCustomerButton);
      print("Add customer page is opened");
    });

    test("Adding text in textfield", () async {
      await driver.tap(find.byValueKey("CustomerBusinessName"));
      await sleep(Duration(seconds: 5));
      await driver.enterText('Hello !');

      await driver.tap(find.byValueKey("CustomerPhoneNumber"));
      await driver.enterText('1234567890');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you should approach this problem slightly differently. You can use tester for both creating the element and interacting with it. [Docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/widget/tap-drag)

```
await tester.pumpWidget(testWidget);
await tester.enterText(find.byKey(Key("titleInput")), "title");
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll first need to tell `driver` to wait till the element ie `CustomerBusinessName` textField is located and then tap on it and then directly enter text. No need to wait or sleep for 5 seconds between tap and enter text actions, because driver first needs to locate the element and then perform actions on it. I tried by rendering two `TextFields` and was able to enter text in both of them properly. Here's working sample code:

`main.dart`:

```
body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Form(
                  key: Key('inputTextField'),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter name'
                    ),
                  )
              ),
              Form(
                  key: Key('inputTextField1'),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter phone'
                    ),
                  )
              )
            ],
          )
        )
```

[image]

`driver test`:

```
test('enter text', () async {
    final formFinder = find.byValueKey('inputTextField');
    final formFinder1 = find.byValueKey('inputTextField1');

    await driver.waitFor(formFinder);
    await driver.tap(formFinder);
    await driver.enterText('Hello');
    print('entered text');

    await driver.waitFor(formFinder1);
    await driver.tap(formFinder1);
    await driver.enterText('123456');
    print('entered number');
  });
```

test result:

[image]

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. You may accept / upvote my answer so that it'll be helpful for others as well.